# PySpark NoSuchMethodError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner when inserting data into DB

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, py4j

I am receiving this error while trying to insert a large dataframe into Postgres. `NoSuchMethodError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner`

Here is a full error.
There are a lot of operations before, so there are no reason in attaching them to the question.

Could you please give some pieces of advice, what may solve the problem. Or where is it better to search for answers.

```
  File "/home/functions/etl_functions/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o336.jdbc.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 29.0 (TID 1036, spark-02-dev.dev.olabs.global, executor 1): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner()Lsun/misc/Cleaner;
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.cleanDirectBuffer(StorageUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.dispose(StorageUtils.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils.dispose(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.io.NioBufferedFileInputStream.close(NioBufferedFileInputStream.java:130)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillReader.close(UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java:144)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillReader.loadNext(UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java:116)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter$ChainedIterator.loadNext(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:653)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray$SpillableArrayIterator.next(ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray$SpillableArrayIterator.next(ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowFunctionFrame$.getNextOrNull(WindowFunctionFrame.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.OffsetWindowFunctionFrame.write(WindowFunctionFrame.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.next(WindowExec.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.next(WindowExec.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2823)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2343)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:461)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner()Lsun/misc/Cleaner;
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.cleanDirectBuffer(StorageUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.dispose(StorageUtils.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils.dispose(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.io.NioBufferedFileInputStream.close(NioBufferedFileInputStream.java:130)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillReader.close(UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java:144)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillReader.loadNext(UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java:116)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter$ChainedIterator.loadNext(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:653)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray$SpillableArrayIterator.next(ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray$SpillableArrayIterator.next(ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowFunctionFrame$.getNextOrNull(WindowFunctionFrame.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.OffsetWindowFunctionFrame.write(WindowFunctionFrame.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.next(WindowExec.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.next(WindowExec.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: Hello @AntonBondar did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Me personally no, I've passed the issue to DevOps. I've found out that when I'm executing the job on cluster - it crashes with `NoSuchMethodError`. But when I'm running the code on one specific server without cluster, than it's ok. So that means that the problem probably in different java versions.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this set some `--add-opens` as it is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855571/13547620.

Answer (score 1):

Looks that sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer class used by Spark is different than the one installed on your system.  That might be the reason that cleaner method is not found. Please try to ensure that the loaded rt.jar which contains sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer class is the right one.

Find below some related links:

https://coderanch.com/t/600634/java/java-access-restriction-errors-sun

https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/issues/879

Good luck