# Spark Processes are being terminated

Tags: apache-spark

When i tried to run bin\pyspark in cmd i got this error and i have already installed the spark as well as supported python version also

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4504 (child process of PID 4580) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4580 (child process of PID 2976) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 2976 (child process of PID 416) has been terminated.
```

Comment: you'd need to supply more info on what your setup is

Comment: i am using windows 10 and python 3.7 with spark 3.2.1 with hadoop 2.7

Comment: Reason could be  java version incompatibility. Check this thread  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763427/pyspark-not-initialized